# How to duplicate a structure into a pointer with malloc function [C-Programming]

Tags: c, malloc, duplicate-data

I've tried to create a function that duplicate a structure into a pointer, but here is the issue, there is a `char` tab into the structure and I can't assign my original value to the new structure.

The function :

```
Planete *dupliquer(Planete *p){
  Planete *res;  
  res = (Planete*) malloc(sizeof(Planete));
  if(res == NULL){
    printf("Erreur d'allocation...\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  res->nomplanete = p->nomplanete;
  res->rayon = p->rayon;

  return res;
}
```

And here is the compilator error :

```
 error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[20]’ from type ‘char *’
   res->nomplanete = p->nomplanete;
                   ^
```

Can you please help me, It will be very nice. Thanks for your support !

Comment: `memcpy(res, p, sizeof(Planete))`

Comment: "duplicate a structure into a pointer"  Huh?

Comment: Thanks but I have to use the malloc function, do you have any solution for my error ?

Comment: @tux3 has already given a simple solution, but for future reference note that your problem is caused by trying to use `=` to assign char * strings (you would need to use strcpy or similar for this). Also note that [you should not cast the result of malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Don't cast the return value of `malloc()` it's not necessary.

Comment: I create a Planete, the I duplicate it into a pointer I created and allocate into memory

Comment: I don't really understand the cast behind the malloc, this is my teacher instruction ^^

Comment: @KevinMasson Your teacher is bad, tell them to go [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: Ahah @Lundin, unfortunatelly, i can't :p

Comment: Well, this is a major problem in the whole software industry: way too many crappy teachers and crappy books.

Comment: I shown it to my teacher and he didn't understand why it works x) Thank you :)

Comment: Your teacher is probably confused between C and C++ - in C you should not use a cast with malloc, in C++ you have to (but then you shouldn't be using malloc in C++ anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you do not need a separate `malloc` for `nomplanete`, because it is an array. In situations like that you should use `strcpy`, like this:

```
strcpy(res->nomplanete, p->nomplanete);
```

If all members of `Planete` are primitives or arrays, you could simply `memcpy` the entire thing, like this:

```
res = malloc(sizeof(Planete)); // No need to cast
if(res == NULL){
    printf("Erreur d'allocation...\n");
    exit(1);
}
memcpy(res, p, sizeof(Planete));
```

If `nomplanete` were a pointer, you would have to do a separate `malloc` or use `strdup`:

```
res->nomplanete = malloc(1+strlen(p->nomplanete));
strcpy(res->nomplanete, p->nomplanete);
```

Comment: If "nomplanete" was an array as member of the struct, then memcpy() on the whole struct would have worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that "nomplanete" is a character array member of the "Planete" struct. In that case, simply write the function as:

```
Planete* dupliquer (const Planete* p)
{
  Planete* res;  
  res = malloc(sizeof(Planete));
  if(res == NULL){
    printf("Erreur d'allocation...\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  memcpy(res, p, sizeof(Planete));

  return res;
}
```

Comment: Finally, I've used strcpy beceause we had to do it without memcpy ^ ^ 
Thanks !